# Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber) returns java.lang.nullpointer exception even when row exist in Excel sheet. I am using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

EDIT:   I am using this code to read rows and columns of an excel sheet.But the line marked with double star throws exception(java.lang.nullpointer exception).Apart from this i also want to convert null columns found in between to blank columns.Please help.

There are 2 loops one for row and inner one for column as obvious. Niehter the row is getting read nor the blank cell issue is getting resolved.

```
public void read(String filePath) throws NullPointerException {

                    try {
                    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
                    System.out.println("going to create Workbook object to read excel row wise");// Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
                    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
                    System.out.println("going to create object sheet to read excel row wise");
                    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);  //extracts the first sheet of excel
                    System.out.println("Running row iterator to read excel row wise");

                    for (int rowNumber = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); rowNumber <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNumber++) {
                        if (rowNumber == sheet.getFirstRowNum())// this row was skipped as it was header row.
                        {
                        System.out.println("skipping first row");
                        continue;
                        }
                        this.rowconcat = ""; // all values of perticular row will be concatinated in this variable.
                        this.flag = 0;

                        if (sheet.getRow(rowNumber) == null) {
                            System.out.println("row detected null");
                        } else {
                            // The row has data
                            System.out.println("row no inside else==="+rowNumber);
                            **Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);**  //This line here throws null pointer exception.
                        for (int cellNumber = row.getFirstCellNum(); cellNumber <= row.getLastCellNum(); cellNumber++) {
                            Cell cell = row.getCell(cellNumber);
                            if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                                this.flag = 1; // set to 1 to indicate blank cell but this also doesn't work
                                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                                cell.setCellValue(" "); //inserting space in cell after converting its type to String.
                                this.rowconcat = this.rowconcat + cell.getStringCellValue() + "~";
                            } else {
                                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                                this.rowconcat = this.rowconcat + cell.getStringCellValue() + "~";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }//try block closure
               catch(Exception e){
               //autogenerated
                }
            } // function closure
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the line that throws the exception?  That doesn't seem possible to me.

Comment: But is that the line that's mentioned in the stack trace?

Comment: You may want to print another line right after the line that you suspect. If only to convince the rest of us.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend JXL library better the appache one, I have worked with it sinc elong time. Its only minor problem is that it works only with xls not xlsx (if no updates have taken place till now!).

Have a small example for that:

```
File xlsFile;
public void manageData ()
{
        Workbook w;
        try {
            w = Workbook.getWorkbook(xlsFile);
            // Get the first sheet
            Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
            int j = 1;
            //Begin from the second row
            while (j < sheet.getColumns()) {
                //staff
                Cell infoCell = sheet.getCell(j, 4);
                System.out.println(infoCell.getContents());
            }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i am told to work solely on xlsx format. And a lot has been already done using Apache POI.